# Visual Studio 2013 creating too many log files in C:\Windows\Temp directory

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2013.  After a couple of weeks I found thousands of MSI*.LOG files had been created in my C:\Windows\Temp directory - almost 30Gb worth.  Each file is virtually the same and is about 3.1Mb.  It appears to be installing the same thing over and over.  I can delete all of the files, but they start to reappear almost immediately.  I have placed a snippet of one of the files below.  I am new to posting on StackOverflow so I'm not sure if I need to put more of the file or all of the file or what.  I found 2 other articles on the internet suggesting issues with VS2013 so I have gone through the Repair process as well as uninstalling/reinstalling VS2013.  I did notice that after I uninstalled VS2013 that no more files were created, but they started to appear again after I reinstalled VS2013.

I didn't receive any errors during VS2013 installation.  I am able to create new solutions/projects and everything seems to compile/build just fine so I am at a loss as to what the problem could be.

Has anyone seen this issue?  Is there a resolution that solves the problem?  I'm looking for something other than just "clean up the files every night"!

```
=== Verbose logging started: 12/1/2014  12:29:41  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorsvw.exe ===
MSI (c) (9C:18) [12:29:41:414]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (9C:18) [12:29:41:414]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (9C:18) [12:29:41:414]: ******* RunEngine:
       ******* Product: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}
       ******* Action: 
       ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (9C:18) [12:29:41:414]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (9C:18) [12:29:41:414]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (9C:18) [12:29:41:414]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (9C:18) [12:29:41:414]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (9C:18) [12:29:41:430]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (84:94) [12:29:41:430]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}
MSI (s) (84:94) [12:29:41:430]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:430]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:430]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:430]: ******* RunEngine:
       ******* Product: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}
       ******* Action: 
       ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:430]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:445]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:445]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:445]: Original package ==> C:\Windows\Installer\4c8872.msi
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:445]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\4c8872.msi
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:461]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall Flags override found.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:461]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall VersionNT override found.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:461]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall ServicePackLevel override found.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:461]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}'.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:461]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:461]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:461]: Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\3007d0.msp'.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:461]: Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\2fe190.msp'.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:461]: Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\20c3cd.msp'.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\20c3cc.msp'.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: SequencePatches starts. Product code: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}, Product version: 12.0.21005, Upgrade code: {015856DA-C69D-3EE0-85EC-270367A147A1}, Product language 1033
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: SequencePatches returns success.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: Final Patch Application Order:
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: {BFB5154E-888D-4D0E-B377-018AF8B74968} - 
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: {C823005E-3448-3126-A3E5-9B568096F87A} - 
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: {1B46DFCA-9504-4ACD-AB79-FBC3C899784E} - 
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: {1F654618-A065-3008-9415-576BB5F0E42D} - 
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.1
DEBUG: Error 2746:  Transform RTM.1 invalid for package C:\Windows\Installer\4c8872.msi. Expected product {7781AFF2-D0BE-364B-B18A-D7DBEF8B712D}, found product {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}.
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: Skipping validation for patch transform #RTM.1.  Will not apply because previous transform was invalid
MSI (s) (84:DC) [12:29:41:477]: Looking for patch transform: RTM.2
1: 2746 2: RTM.1 3: C:\Windows\Installer\4c8872.msi 4: {7781AFF2-D0BE-364B-B18A-D7DBEF8B712D} 5: {9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/736253/too-many-log-files-being-created-in-temp-folder

Comment: Yes, this was one of 2 articles I found which indicated it was an issue with VS2013.  However, after trying to repair VS2013 (as well as uninstall/reinstall), I was still seeing the .log files being created.

Comment: Same here! Fills up my free space! Usually I don't even use my local VS 2013 (I work using a remote host through RDP). VS 2013 fills up my log even if I don't start it! o_O

Comment: VS Repair seems to solved it so far

Answer (score 3):

After running repair from the Visual Studio installer the problem seems to be resolved. I lost some gigs, but there's no more daily fillup.

Comment: Well, I thought I had gone through the repair process before I posted my issue, but I went ahead and tried it again given Csaba Toth's success and it has indeed resolved my issue.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: I wish could determine the root cause, but as a developer I have so many versions of Visual Studios, other IDEs, SDKs and other related stuff installed, that it's very hard to point out the culprit. This started not so long ago, some months ago though. Maybe after I installed the VS 2013 community edition? Or the VS Update 4?

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem started after installing Update 5 for VS 2013 Community Edition. Repairing didn't resolve the problem.

However, I found [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2015/04/20/visual-studio-2013-continuously-repairs-producing-many-small-log-files.aspx) on [Heath Stewart's MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/) and it helped in my case.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2015/04/20/visual-studio-2013-continuously-repairs-producing-many-small-log-files.aspx